# View type not found in customControl

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I created a Custom Control, follow this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1LhXdCTsn4. When I access to View, the app crash and exit.

There are my log.

```
mvx:Diagnostic: 28,78 Showing ViewModel DrawingViewModel
06-10 00:26:39.499 I/mvx     (26433):  28,78 Showing ViewModel DrawingViewModel
06-10 00:26:39.499 I/mono-stdout(26433): mvx:Diagnostic: 28,78 Showing ViewModel     DrawingViewModel
mvx:Diagnostic: 29,03 Loading new ViewModel from Intent with Extras
06-10 00:26:39.748 I/mvx     (26433):  29,03 Loading new ViewModel from Intent with    Extras
06-10 00:26:39.768 I/mono-stdout(26433): mvx:Diagnostic: 29,03 Loading new ViewModel   from Intent with Extras
MvxBind:Error: 29,12 View type not found - mymvvmcross.droid.controls.DrawingBoardControl
06-10 00:26:39.848 I/MvxBind (26433):  29,12 View type not found - mymvvmcross.droid.controls.DrawingBoardControl
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the error. Had properties within the control of the parent invalidate the key "new".

Now I have another problem, within the control I have a list, but does not make binding

Answer (score 2):

`View type not found` suggests your custom view/widget can't be found.

Is `mymvvmcross.droid.controls.DrawingBoardControl` the correct path?

Does the code for that sample work on your machine? - https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-18-CustomControls

If it does, then can you spot any differences between that and your code?

> Any idea?

If you want ideas, then you really need to post a bit of your code - e.g. the xml references your control and some of the C# for your control itself

Comment: Yes, is correct path, because I set breakpoint inside the control and stop. 

Yes, I try the code <https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-18-CustomControls> and works.